# spray json implicit UUID conversion

Tags: scala, spray-json

I have a User model

```
case class User(name: String, email: String, password: Option[String] = None, key: Option[UUID] = None)
```

With a spray-json marshaller

```
object UserJsonSupport extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport {
  implicit val userFormat = jsonFormat4(User)
}
```

It was working until I converted the key field from `Option[String]` to `Option[UUID]` and I now get two compilation errors:

```
Error:(8, 40) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type in.putfood.http.UserJsonSupport.JF[Option[java.util.UUID]]
  implicit val userFormat = jsonFormat4(User)
                                       ^
Error:(8, 40) not enough arguments for method jsonFormat4: (implicit evidence$16: in.putfood.http.UserJsonSupport.JF[String], implicit evidence$17: in.putfood.http.UserJsonSupport.JF[String], implicit evidence$18: in.putfood.http.UserJsonSupport.JF[Option[String]], implicit evidence$19: in.putfood.http.UserJsonSupport.JF[Option[java.util.UUID]], implicit evidence$20: ClassManifest[in.putfood.model.User])spray.json.RootJsonFormat[in.putfood.model.User].
Unspecified value parameters evidence$19, evidence$20.
  implicit val userFormat = jsonFormat4(User)
                                   ^
```

My understanding was that since [this issue](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/issues/24) was resolved, it should just work without needed to provide my own UUID unserializer. Am I mistaken or is it something else entirely?

Is it possible it doesn't like being inside an `Option`?

Answer (score 6):

It probably should've been resolved, however, I ran into the same issue lately (While using `akka-http v10.0.0`) and I was able to resolve it by defining the following

```
  implicit object UUIDFormat extends JsonFormat[UUID] {
    def write(uuid: UUID) = JsString(uuid.toString)
    def read(value: JsValue) = {
      value match {
        case JsString(uuid) => UUID.fromString(uuid)
        case _              => throw new DeserializationException("Expected hexadecimal UUID string")
      }
    }
  }
```

The solution was borrowed from [Fidesmo API](https://github.com/fidesmo/spray-example/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/fidesmo/examples/spray/Models.scala).

---

Update:

I added a library that go through the most common use cases.
<[Link here](https://github.com/LocalInc/akka-http-marshaller)>

Answer (score 0):

The issue mentioned referenced a PR that was closed, not merged. The reason is also provided there:

```
I want to cancel this Pull Request – there are instances where non-String serialisation is useful.

In scalad, we're creating custom marshallers for Date and UUID so that the Mongo backend can serialise them correctly.
```

So, please stick with mamdouh's answer. It's not a big deal to create a custom format.